# How to resize my label Tensor so I can us it in tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following problem:

```
 cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=logits)
```

This gives me

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 18000 for 'remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [1024,18000]
```

which makes sense because the function expects something one dimensional. So I tried:

```
cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.argmax(labels, axis=1), logits=logits)
```

which gives me

```
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((1024, 18000) vs (1024,))
```

So my labels are just images of a certain size, so I am a bit lost here how I should give the function something onedimensional when my labels have more dimensions :/

Comment: Can you describe a bit more your model, the input and the output? Thanks